# Annoying selection space in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I select a block of code in VS Code I get the following:

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwjkA.png)

At the end of each line, and at the beginning of the selection, the editor selects an extra space (that isn't actually there). How can I stop it from doing this? I want the selection to be exactly the text that I select and nothing else.

Comment: I don't see any extra spaces selected in your png.  The dots are spaces and there aren't any before your selection or at the end of lines.

Comment: at the end of the line it is the **linefeed** that is selected

Comment: can I get rid of linefeed selection?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.